# 10400コードエラー

Tags: paypal

PayPalのSetExpressCheckoutのAPIを呼び出したところ、レスポンスでエラーコード10400が返ってきたのですが、

https://www.paypal.jp/uploadedFiles/wwwpaypaljp/Supporting_Content/jp/manual/PP_JP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide_JP.pdf

によると、「OrderTotalがありません。」との記載になっていますが、
下記のパラメータ以外に必要なものはありますでしょうか。

```
[パラメーター]
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&VERSION=52.0
&USER=***
&PWD=****** 
&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXX
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19.5
&RETURNURL=XXXXXXX
&CANCELURL=XXXXXXX""

[レスポンス]
TIMESTAMP=2015-05-28T08:22:13Z
&CORRELATIONID=******
&ACK=Failure
&VERSION=52.0
&BUILD=7333778
&L_ERRORCODE0=10400
&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Order total is missing.
&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Answer (score 1):

指定しているversionが古いので新しくしましょう。VERSION=122.0 で試してください。

古いバージョンではPAYMENTREQUEST_0_* というパラメータが認識されないので
必須である、PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMTパラメータが指定なしとみなされて起こるエラーだと思います。

なお、通貨はデフォルトで米国ドルです。
日本円で決済する場合は、PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=JPY を送信して下さい。
また、日本円の場合、PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMTの値は整数を指定してください。